# How to get a user location and hometown from facebook graph API using facebook ID

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I need user location and hometown from facebook API

I have the facebook Id of a user say `1086`, and use this url to `https://graph.facebook.com/1086?fields=id%2Cname%2Clocation` it returns only `name` an `id`. I also tried with `access_token`. In `access token` `user_location` is enabled. Still I am not getting the result.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1086?fields=id%2Cname%2Clocation&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN
```

Comment: And that access token is for the user with that specific user id …?

Comment: yes it is for the  specific user id

Comment: Have you [debugged](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) your access token to see if it really contains `user_location` permission?

Comment: The Facebook [token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) is here, the one mentioned above can not crawl Facebook URL's. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code.
    scope="public_profile,email,user_location,user_hometown" 
I hope it helps you out